# Is it possible to show that $\frac{{n-a-1 \choose b-2}}{{n-1\choose b-1}-{n-2\choose b-2}}\leq\frac{b}{n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $n,a,b$ be positive values such that $a,b\ll n$.

Is it possible to show that $\frac{{n-a-1 \choose b-2}}{{n-1\choose b-1}-{n-2\choose b-2}}\leq\frac{b}{n}$? If inequality is impossible, can we still get $\sim b/n$?

My idea is to simplify the denominator to ${n-2\choose b-2}\frac{n-b}{b-1}$, but this doesn't seem to quite work.

Comment: Any constraint on $a$? Is it allowed to be negative?

Comment: No. Only positive.

Comment: I've edited the question for more clarity, thanks.

Comment: Is this part of some larger question? Is it required to show or solve the inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint given by @Đào Minh Dũng
$$u_n=\frac{{n-a-1 \choose b-2}}{{n-1\choose b-1}-{n-2\choose b-2}}=\frac{\binom{n-a-1}{b-2}}{\binom{n-2}{b-1}}$$ Write in terms of factorials, take logarithms and use Stirling approximation, compose Taylor series to get
$$u_n =\frac {b-1}n \left(1+\frac{2b-a (b-2)-2}{n} \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** ${n-1\choose b-1}-{n-2\choose b-2} = {n-2 \choose b-1}$. Then expand the expressions and cancel out similar terms

Comment: Only the $(b-1)!$ and $(b-2)!$ terms cancel, no? I'm still left with the remaining factorials which does not cancel out nicely to get me the inequality.